# How can I fix error on validation of complex sql statement in Room in android studio during compile?

Tags: android, sqlite, compiler-errors, android-room

I current have a sql statement for one of my DAO query statements:

```
    @Query(
            "select " +
            "    avg(q1.weight) over (rows between 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as adjusted_weight " +
            "from weight_record AS q1 " +
            "order by q1.date"
    )
    LiveData<List<AggregatedWeightRecord>> getAggregatedRecords();
```

When I try this query directly inside sqlite3 it works flawlessly. When I put it in Android Studio and try to compile I get this error:

```
error: extraneous input '(' expecting {<EOF>, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}

extraneous input ')' expecting {<EOF>, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}
```

I have tried to change the query but I need to use windows for now. I also added @SkipQueryVerification before @Query but i still get the error.

What are my options to get this compiled and have ability for LiveData at the same time?

Comment: Try it with `@RawQuery`: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery. If that fails, then that suggests there is a legitimate SQLite syntax issue, and SQLite's own error might give you more clues (string concatenation problems?). If `@RawQuery` works, that's at least your workaround.

Comment: Try using a variable to hold the query statement then use variable inside @Query(variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you will have to use an alternative query that doesn't use Window Functions.

Support for Window functions and therefore the use of **OVER** was introduced in [SQLite 3.25.0](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html).

The highest supported version of SQLite in the official Android list is SQLite 3.19. As such **OVER** is invalid syntax and you cannot use Window functions.
[android.database.sqlite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary)

Comment: Thank you for the info. For everyone that may find this answer useful, the solution is a combination of Cartesian or cross join with an auto increment column. it will be messy but doable.